# Onion Architecture: Should UI project have access to Domain Layer?

Tags: java, c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I'm looking at `Onion Architecture` pie and I'm confused...

[image]

Should UI Client have access to `Domain Model` and `Domain Services`? Or only to `Application Services` and `Core`?

To be exact, I'm asking: should UI Project has references to Domain projects?

Comment: I hate this kind of dogma.  I think the answer depends on a lot of things.  I'd give you a different answer if you were writing a web UI that communicated with REST web services.  This is where anti-patterns like DTO layers that preserve "purity" come from.

Comment: Usually things shouldn't have direct access to anything but their direct neighbours. Because the result can easily become a messy network of dependencies. But I don't see that violated as long as you gain access to your domain objects through app services / app core.

Comment: I'm talking about talking about things like `Enums` or other `Entites`. For example when application service method takes `Enum` as parameter or return object of some `Entity`. In that case, should that `Enum` or `Entity` be moved to Core?

Comment: Application core is not a separate layer, it's a common term for domain model, domain services and app services together.

Comment: @duffymo Can you explain this: "This is where anti-patterns like DTO layers that preserve "purity" come from." ?

Comment: Go read about the J2EE design patterns and DTOs.  They are the problem I'm referring to.  I think it's a waste to create a separate layer of objects that mirror your domain model simply to pass them to a UI layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I don't believe there is a good reason to avoid UI Layer to know and use Domain Objects. It is obvious that if you do that, you are coupling UI Layer to Bussines Layer, but in the end, won't UI Layer depends on bussines?

On the other hand, the opposite is not desirable, it is no good practice to couple bussines to UI Layer. What if you want to have several UI Layers accessing the same bussines? That's the point.

But keep in mind that there is no golden hammer. Don't look for definitive rules about software design, but learn SOLID principles, it is worthy.

Comment: I know that opposite is not desirable. But I thought (for a second) that everything from Domain that is used in UI client should be moved to Core layer

Comment: It is quite common to use domain objects as a traversal layer, but this does not mean that you have to use it always in this way.

Comment: Yes, but only objects like Types or Enums. When I have a function (let's say method in Domain Entity) I'm using it in Application Service, and Application Service in UI.

Comment: I am assuming Domain services is Repository layer. Now questions is how can I let my UI layer to persist a new domain object using repository. This should only be done using application services. Because, application services validate the domain model and run some other rules before persisting this domain object into data store.

Answer (score 4):

The most important concept in onion architecture and similar concepts is to keep the domain layer independent. It is achieved by restricting the dependencies to always point inside the diagram you posted.

A reference from UI project to Domain project doesn't break this rule.

The UI layer should just send commands to application layer for every use case. However even with such a clean separation of concerns you might want to include some domain layer objects in these commands - the simplest examples that come to mind are value types and enums.

A quote from [Robert C. Martin's blog](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) about dependencies:

> The Dependency Rule
>
> The concentric circles represent different areas of software. In general, the further in you go, the higher level the software becomes. The outer circles are mechanisms. The inner circles are policies.
>
> The overriding rule that makes this architecture work is The Dependency Rule. This rule says that source code dependencies can only point inwards. Nothing in an inner circle can know anything at all about something in an outer circle. In particular, the name of something declared in an outer circle must not be mentioned by the code in the an inner circle. That includes, functions, classes. variables, or any other named software entity.
>
> By the same token, data formats used in an outer circle should not be used by an inner circle, especially if those formats are generate by a framework in an outer circle. We don’t want anything in an outer circle to impact the inner circles.

**Edit**

In your comments you mention moving entities from Domain layer to application core. In [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), the term 'Application core' means Domain model + Domain services + Application services. It's not a separate layer.

Comment: Thanks! Now that all makes more sense

Comment: I am assuming Domain services is Repository layer. Now questions is how can I let my UI layer to persist a new domain object using repository. This should only be done using application services. Because, application services validate the domain model and run some other rules before persisting this domain object into data stor